# Transparent status bar on Cordova apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, android-statusbar

Is there any way to set the status bar on Cordova apps, both Android and iOS, to be transparent? 
If I don't use the Cordova StatusBar plugin the status bar on iOS will be transparent but it will also overlap the navigation bar. In Android it will have some default color.
If I use the StatusBar plugin I have to set a color value which will be applied to both Android and iOS.
All possible solutions I found online doesn't work for me.
Any ideas?

**Update 07/12-17**
I have tried some different solutions but nothing works, so I have another question. Is there anyway to set different colors on the statusbar on different pages in the app?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020 the below solution seems to be the only working method for iOS.

Install:
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
   Plugins.StatusBar.setOverlaysWebView({overlay: true});
   Plugins.StatusBar.setBackgroundColor({color: '#33000000'});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

I just found it, its not mention in their documentation, but its simple as that:

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="transparent" />
```